# Meteor - How to Use a Package in Dev or Production Only

Tags: javascript, meteor

In Meteor, is there a way to specify a package to be used in the development environment only, or the production environment only? When I add packages via astmospherejs.com, they all get lumped into the `.meteor/packages` file sorted chronologically by time added. Essentially, I'm looking for what would be a ruby Gemfile, where you can specify different environments. Thanks!

Comment: Well, in the `Package.describe` callback (`package.js` file) you can set `debugOnly: true` in order to not deploy the package when using `meteor deploy`, for example to use a collection populating code you don't want to use in prod. Hope it will help!

Comment: Useful. Unfortunately, this is [not yet documented](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3843). I'm looking for a "productionOnly" but that doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a little trick I've been using to run a package in development only:

1. from your app root, create a blank package (or add to your `PACKAGE_DIRS` directory): `meteor create --package my-package-manager`
2. In package.js:

   ```
   Package.on_use(function(api) {
     // production only
     if (process.env.IS_PRODUCTION) {
       api.use('some:package');
     }
     // dev only
     if (process.env.IS_DEVELOPMENT) {
       api.use('devonly:package');
     }
   });
   ```
3. On dev environment: `echo "export IS_DEVELOPMENT=true" >> ~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.zshrc` in my case)
4. Then obviously do the same thing for `IS_PRODUCTION` on whatever you use for production server. on heroku for example: `heroku config:set IS_PRODUCTION=true`

I'm using this for a dev-only package, haven't tried it with production-only but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for this useful tip. Meteor lacks the flexibility of Gemfile. You can also use `process.env.NODE_ENV` for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

From meteor version 1.3.2, you can simply put the flag `prodOnly` or `debugOnly`.

More info [here](https://docs.meteor.com/api/packagejs.html#PackageNamespace-describe)

Comment: This link is broken now

Comment: Thank you for notifying me about this, I have updated the link